# recursive cte working very slow

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I want to Group the rows based on certain columns, i.e. if data is same in these columns in continuous rows, then assign same Group Number to them, and if its changed, assign new one. This become complex as the same data in the columns could appear later in some other rows, so they have to be given another Group Number as they are not in continuous rows with previous group.
I used **cte** for this purpose and it is giving correct output also, but is so slow that iterating over 75k+ rows takes about 15 minutes. The code I used is:

```
WITH 
cte  AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Patient_ID, Opnamenummer, SPECIALISMEN, Opnametype, OntslagDatumTijd) AS RowNumber, 
           Opnamenummer, Patient_ID, AfdelingsCode, Opnamedatum, Opnamedatumtijd, Ontslagdatum, Ontslagdatumtijd, IsSpoedopname, OpnameType, IsNuOpgenomen, SpecialismeCode, Specialismen
      FROM t_opnames)

SELECT * INTO #ttt FROM cte;

WITH cte2 AS (SELECT TOP 1 RowNumber, 
                 1 AS GroupNumber, 
                 Opnamenummer, Patient_ID, AfdelingsCode, Opnamedatum, Opnamedatumtijd, Ontslagdatum, Ontslagdatumtijd, IsSpoedopname, OpnameType, IsNuOpgenomen, SpecialismeCode, Specialismen
      FROM #ttt
      ORDER BY RowNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c1.RowNumber, 
           CASE
               WHEN c2.Afdelingscode <> c1.Afdelingscode
                 OR c2.Patient_ID <> c1.Patient_ID
                 OR c2.Opnametype <> c1.Opnametype 
            THEN c2.GroupNumber + 1
               ELSE c2.GroupNumber
           END AS GroupNumber, 
           c1.Opnamenummer,c1.Patient_ID,c1.AfdelingsCode,c1.Opnamedatum,c1.Opnamedatumtijd,c1.Ontslagdatum,c1.Ontslagdatumtijd,c1.IsSpoedopname,c1.OpnameType,c1.IsNuOpgenomen, SpecialismeCode, Specialismen
   FROM cte2 c2
    JOIN #ttt c1 ON c1.RowNumber = c2.RowNumber + 1
   ) 

SELECT *
  FROM cte2
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) ;

 DROP TABLE #ttt
```

I tried to improve performance by putting output of cte in a temp table. That increased the performance, but still its too slow. So, how can I increase the performance of this code to **run it under 10 seconds for 75k+ records?** The output before cancelling the query is: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZXvK.png). As visible from the image, data is same in columns Afdelingscode,Patient_ID and Opnametype in RowNumber 3,5 and 6, but they have different GroupNumber because of concurrency of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Without data its not that easy to test but i would try first to not use temporary table and just use both cte from start to end, ie;

```
;WITH 
cte  AS (...),
cte2 AS (...) 
select * from cte2 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Without knowing indices etc... for instance, you do a lot of ordering in the first cte. Is this supported by indices (or one multicolumn index) or not?

Without the data i don't have the option to play with it but looking at this:

```
CASE
  WHEN    c2.Afdelingscode <> c1.Afdelingscode
       OR c2.Patient_ID <> c1.Patient_ID
       OR c2.Opnametype <> c1.Opnametype 
          THEN c2.GroupNumber + 1
  ELSE c2.GroupNumber
```

i would try to take a look at `partition by` statement in row_number

So try to run this:

```
WITH 
cte  AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Afdelingscode , Patient_ID  ,Opnametype  ORDER BY Patient_ID, Opnamenummer, SPECIALISMEN, Opnametype, OntslagDatumTijd ) AS RowNumber, 
           Opnamenummer, Patient_ID, AfdelingsCode, Opnamedatum, Opnamedatumtijd, Ontslagdatum, Ontslagdatumtijd, IsSpoedopname, OpnameType, IsNuOpgenomen
      FROM t_opnames)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Please see this Fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6aac5/1/0). I have created this fiddle with sample data. I cannot use partition as it will unorganize the rows and I will have to use Order By again in the last select statement which would again decrease the performance. I tried that already.

Comment: in fiddle: 
Time with your solution 4ms fill temp table + 6ms run select + 2ms drop table (12ms total)
Time with your solution but without temp table: 8ms
Time with partition by and order by: 3ms

Please note that:
Fiddle contains only 10 rows. this is a small data set. With 75k rows, the execution plan can get totally different so this is not much of an help.
take a look if you have index/indices on the Partition by and Order by columns and if yes, what indices.

In addition, please post execution plan for your solution and the partition by solution including the queries. thank you

Comment: I have index in the table, I have a clustered index on the column "ID". So if I should add index on the "Order By" columns, which would be good, clustered or non clustered?

Comment: I asume that there is only one index, the primary key clustered index. That means that there already is a clustered and there cant be more then 1 clustered. but that is not important.

I would go with:
`create index SomedescriptiveNameForIndex on t_opnames (Afdelingscode , Patient_ID  ,Opnametype)` and `create index SomedescriptiveNameForIndex2 on t_opnames (Patient_ID, Opnamenummer, SPECIALISMEN, Opnametype, OntslagDatumTijd)`

Comment: I am getting this warning while creating these Indices, `Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'Idx1' has maximum length of 2048 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
`

Comment: holy batdatabase..... what kind of fields do you have....
Can you provide info on the size of fields? data type and length?
Did you try the indexes i told you or some others?

Comment: You are correct, its bad database design. All the fields in this table are of type NVARCHAR(255). I guess I will have to reduce their size.